# after first reboot choose wrong video port

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, vga, dvi

Sorry for my english. 
I had installed Ubuntu 12.04 on intel motherboard with atom and igd 3000.
On this board two video outputs: d-sub(vga) and dvi.
My monitor have only D-SUB.
After installation sytem was updated/upgraded and of course rebooted.

BIOS, POST... and black screen.

Some more rebooting... nothing changed.

I had an idea that Ubuntu choose wrong output videoport. 
Brought from a neighbor another monitor with DVI.
And had the ubuntu on the screen.

But in the settings is missing VGA monitor.

Any idea/help?

---

I have only integrated graphic, and no pci/pci-ex ports

I think need to edit some config to correct video mode.
Because on another monitor that has resolution 1920*1080 it works, but on 17" with 1280*1024 not.

---

After some more manipulation ubuntu had started at 17" monitor. but only once. ANd i can see that ubuntu think that there is two monitors: one is my 17" and another named "laptop". And output in that laptop, all features in setting window is blocked.

I don't know what to do next.

---

Just reinstall distributive. And step by step watching.
Ubuntu see two monitors, one of them is my Samsung connected via VGA, and other called laptop connected via LVDS. But I had only only one Samsung via VGA... and no any LVDS port. So, when i turned off lvds display in settings it turn off samsung.

Ubuntu see my samsung as LVDS connected display with resolution 1920*1280 and show me just a part off Desktop because samsung  have maximum resolution 1280*1024. And any changing off resolution of any display turning off video outputs. And if I use xrandr and it options nothing happen.

But this is the other problem, which I think could find in other forums.

Comment: Dont's add solved in your title, add your answer as an answer tot he question or accept an answer below.

Comment: Thnx, did not know about it

Comment: I'd be interested to know how you solved this.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this off in BIOS by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> / <kbd>Del</kbd> / <kbd>F10</kbd> on startup; go to Chipset configuration > Initial display mode > PCi-E and if there is a setting to change shared memory, change it to auto and the onboard graphics will disappear in Ubuntu, so it can only select one.

Comment: IGD has been previously switched to default.

Comment: IGD has been previously switched to default, because motherboard without any pci slots

Comment: If it was not configured BIOS I was able to solve it myself.